# Bean could not be found in Spring Boot Lombok Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok, spring-bean

I get the following exception:

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in RController required a bean of type 'UmaEvaluator' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'UmaEvaluator' in your configuration.
```

If you need any more details, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

And here the class definitions:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConditionalOnBean(SecurityConfig.class)
public class UmaEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

}

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    static MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(
        UmaEvaluator umaEvaluator) {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(umaEvaluator);
    return expressionHandler;

}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class RController {

    private final RService rService;

    private final UmaEvaluator umaEvaluator;
}
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't be using the conditional here.  In the docs, spring recommends only placing this on autoconfiguration classes.  Spring can resolve your dependencies, so less is more.